# Do we get good rewards for learning or studying about Islam?

Tags: muslim-practices, reward, knowing-islam

I am trying to be a better Muslim by gaining knowledge. I am constantly watching videos about the Prophets and other Islam topics. I am also reading about Islam whenever I feel like I need to know something.

Do I get good rewards by learning about Islam? Does it count as a good deed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed. You do get rewarded for learning Islam. How else can a person be a Muslim if they don't even seek knowledge about their religion?

**Read! in the Name of your Lord Who has created [all that exists]. He has created man from a clot [a piece of thick coagulated blood]. Read! And your Lord is the Most Bountiful, Who has taught [writing] by the pen. He has taught man that which he knew not. (Al-`Alaq 96:1-5).**

“He who follows a path in quest of knowledge, Allah will make the path to Paradise easy for him. The angels lower their wings for the seeker of knowledge, being pleased with what he does. The inhabitants of the heavens and the earth and even the fish in the depth of the oceans seek forgiveness for him. The superiority of the learned person over the devout worshipper is like that of the moon over rest of the stars. The learned are the heirs of the Prophets; the Prophets bequeath neither dinar nor dirham but only knowledge, and he who acquires it has, in fact, acquired an abundant portion.” (Al-Tirmidhi)